# Spectral Function Sum Rules

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

In let's say, $SU(3)_L\times SU(3)_R$ approximate symmetry in QCD, what are the operators that can appear in operator product expansion of current of like and unlike chirality?

For reference, you could look at Section 20.5, Weinberg QFT 2. I am not completely understanding how to decide based on symmetry and symmetry breaking pattern which operators can appear. Let me know if you have clearer idea.